# Limiting static extension resolution to narrowest matching signature

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have two static extension methods that are similar in that one takes an IEnumerable and the other just T. They each return an ExpandoObject and I have two for optimization purposes since I use Reflection within each.

Here are my method signatures:

`public static ExpandoObject DoSomething<TSource>(this TSource source, string somethingElse)`

`public static ExpandoObject DoSomething<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string somethingElse)`

I wrote the latter one first and then I wrote out the unit test to verify it, it passed. I then wrote the former extension and now my unit test with an IEnumerable is failing because it's matching to the TSource (as List) instead of matching to the IEnumerable signature.

I would have expected that it would pick the most narrow extension to match to, but while it shows as a match to either signature in the Intellisense, it always picks the non-IEnumerable implementation (and I cannot identify a way to override that selection).

1) Is there any way to force it to pick a narrower match or otherwise select which extension I'm seeking to use? 
2) Alternatively, is there any way to guard the types passed in to guard the TSource implementation from receiving any IEnumerable types?

*Edit*:
Playing around with this further, I'm still confused as to how the compiler picks the appropriate extension to use.

If I inform the type of an output instead of using a var, as in the following, it still picks the Object approach and returns only a single ExpandoObject instead of an IEnumerable of them:

`IEnumerable<MyObj> data = new List<MyObj>();
var results = results.DoSomething("");`

This will properly map up to the extension that returns an IEnumerable, but if I do the following:

`var data = new List<MyObj>();
var results = results.DoSomething("");`

The compiler will opt for the Object-based approach instead and will return a single ExpandoObject.

Given that List implements IEnumerable, why does the compiler opt to map to an object for determining the appropriate extension instead of selecting the IEnumerable version, unless I explicitly cast the variable for the input as an IEnumerable?

So question #3 then - what informs the compiler to pick which one to use? It clearly will pick the narrowest option available if it's an explicit type match, but why does it immediately fall back to the widest method even if there's a narrower match available (e.g. a List input)?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense for the compiler to infer which function would be correct in this case (a List is still an Object), so it uses the one which matches all cases.

Simplest way forward is to have a single function which handles both cases.

```
public static object DoSomething<TSource>(this TSource source, string somethingElse)
{
    if (source is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance");
    }
    return null;
}
```